# After refreshing Logout action is not dispatching using ngrx. before refreshing working fine

Tags: angular, ngrx-effects

```
logoutEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.logout),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.authService.signOut().pipe(
        map(() => AuthActions.logoutSuccess()),
        catchError(error => of(AuthActions.logoutFailure({ error }))))
    ),
  );
});
```

this is my logout effect. nothing is happening when i click on logout dispatch. can any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap` ?

Comment: There is no deference using switchMap also,

Comment: can any one help me out, how can i figure it out.